# Controller name from scope of another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Can you help me please?
I want to set controller name which contains in scope of another controller.

JS file:

```
.controller('PageCtrl', [
  '$http',
  '$scope',
  '$routeParams',
  '$location',
  function($http, $scope, $routeParams, $location){

    switch($routeParams.page) {
      case 'companies':
        $scope.CurrentPageCtrl = 'CompaniesCtrl';
      break;
      default:

      break;
    }

  }])

.directive('myPagecontent', function() {
  return {
    template: '<ng-controller ng-controller = "{{CurrentPageCtrl}}"></ng-controller>'
  };
})
```

HTML file:

```
<ng-controller ng-controller = "PageCtrl">
    <my-pagecontent></my-pagecontent>
</ng-controller>
```

And I get error:

```
angular.js:13642 Error: [ng:areq] Argument '{{CurrentPageCtrl}}' is not a function, got undefined
```

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit tricky since `ng-controller` in this case expects an expression that evaluates to a controller constructor function, not to a string that contains the controller name.

One way to solve it is by doing the following:

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', [
  '$http',
  '$scope',
  '$location',
  function($http, $scope, $location) {

    $scope.CurrentPageCtrl = Controller1;
  }
]);

function Controller1($scope) {

  console.log('Controller1');
}

app.controller('Controller1', Controller1);

function Controller2($scope) {

  console.log('Controller2');
}

app.controller('Controller2', Controller2);

app.directive('myPagecontent', function() {
  return {
    template: '<ng-controller ng-controller="CurrentPageCtrl"></ng-controller>'
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/s3yy2fdF5OgBjPcKWikw?p=preview

An alternative solution is to create a directive that runs before everything else, that takes a variable with the controller name, adds `ng-controller` with the correct value and then remove itselves.